# is it possible to get div id as title in browser

Tags: jquery, html

I have a website's page with a menu that links to different divs , on click the pages scroll to the asked div and the rest is invisible.

Is it possible to get the id of the active div as title in the browser ?

Something like this : 
    www.mysite.com/div id

Comment: What you mean? Is it in the title or in the url?

Comment: title or URL name...????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
$(".divSelected").onclick(function(){
    $("#title").html(this.html());
});
```

in your header on the page have

```
<html>
<head>
<title id="title">Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
...
```

Comment: hmmm - misread your question.  You want the url changed - you'd have to do a postback to get that to work

Comment: Hi Peter can you explain me how to do that ? the postback i mean cheers

Comment: I wouldn't bother with that.  You lose all the great features of jquery - you'll lose your scrolling as well.  Unless you really need the div id in the url - I would simple change the title of the page.  Most users look at that anyway.

If you do need to change the url, you just need to put a link in your div

    <div id='menuItem1'><a href='www.mysite.com/menu1'>Menu1</a></div>

but then you will need something on the server to pick that up as a parameter and not a new page.  If you are using MVC - that is relatively easy - but it would depend on what you are using

Comment: Cheers for the advise , i will let it rest

Answer (score 2):

Use the fragment my.url.com/#divid